# Do I need to insert an item?

Tags: swift, core-data

When you create a new SwiftUI app, Xcode creates a file called persistence.swift that contains something like this

```
    for _ in 0..<10 {
        let newItem = Item(context: viewContext)
        newItem.timestamp = Date()
    }
    do {
        try viewContext.save()
```

I have noticed that Apple never uses insert. I would write this like

```
    for _ in 0..<10 {
        let newItem = Item(context: viewContext)
        newItem.timestamp = Date()
        context.insert(newItem) // <<<<<
    }
    do {
        try viewContext.save()
```

Just to confirm, so I do not need the insert there?

If the insert there is not needed in that case, when will it be needed?

Comment: You only need to call the init to have the object inserted into the context. I am not sure about the `insert()` method but since `init(context:)` is a convenience init it wouldn’t surprise me if it actually called `insert()` internally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmanagedobject/1640602-init)

## init(context:)

> Initializes a managed object subclass and **inserts** it into the specified managed object context.

`context.insert` has actually never been used. The usual *old* syntax to insert an item is/was

```
NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName:into:)
```

Comment: It has been used. I've used it.

Answer (score 1):

The `insert()` method is only useful if you've created a new instance that doesn't belong to any managed object context. In some cases it's possible to create an un-inserted item, then insert it later. This can be useful when you create a new object where you might want to save it, but might want to discard it (like if the user presses a "cancel" button). You don't need to use it this case, or in most cases.